# The probability of photon collision

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution, astronomy

I was reading a textbook and I couldn't figure out something that seemed really obvious:
Assume that the space is uniformly and randomly filled with stars, and the mean radial distance between the stars is l. Photons are emitted from a stars's surface in all the directions and can collide with other stars. Now it says that the probability that a photon collides (for the first time) with a star with distance r from the star that it came from, is $$P(r) = l^{-1}e^{-r/l}$$
and did not explain why at all.

Comment: This isn't intended to be an exact representation of the probability: it's an approximation that works reasonably well in a space with a very large number of stars that are very small compared to their distances.  From the point of view of a photon (which thinks very slowly, given that it experiences no real time!) it is passing through a homogeneous "soup" of material, so you don't even need to worry about the structure of space: this is purely a one-dimensional problem (the dimension is along the direction of the photon's travel).